# how to establish internet connection to "ttgo t call esp32 sim800L" using Lua

Tags: lua, nodemcu, esp32

I used the "Nodemcu Module v3" and it supports wifi based internet connection only.

I always start with a wifi initiation steps (By Lua Scripting) to connect my "Nodemcu" board with internet and After making the wifi connection I am sure that my device has access to internet (Though my Wifi router has internet connection) and I can do any internet based communication.

But how can I teach my "ttgo t call esp32 sim800L" board to use the Sim card data?
Is there any steps for that or it connects to internet automatically on insertion of sim card?
Please Guide me to start work on it.

Thank You

Comment: Google gives a lot of tutorials: https://randomnerdtutorials.com/esp32-sim800l-publish-data-to-cloud/, http://www.bizkit.ru/en/2019/04/03/13540/. SIM800L is cheap module with limited functionality and dont expect too much

Comment: Thank you for your precious response. I gone through this, but my doubt is not clear.